# how to show the detail of a card on the other page when the card is clicked ,firebase update from v8 to v9 modular

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
useEffect(() => {
  const q = doc(db, 'movie',id);
  const movieSnapshot = getDoc(q);

    movieSnapshot.then((doc) => {
      if(movieSnapshot.exists()){
        setDetailData(movieSnapshot.doc());
      }
      else{
        console.log(' no movie Movie')
      }
    });

  }, [id]);
```

can anyone help me in passing the id in this code so i can get the id of the document and render the data of that doc on the other?

What I tried:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const q = doc(db, 'movie', id);
  const movieSnapshot = getDoc(q);
  movieSnapshot.then((doc) => {
    if (movieSnapshot.exists()) {
      setDetailData(movieSnapshot.doc());
    } else {
      console.log(' no movie Movie')
    }
  });
}, [id]);
```

Comment: Did you try anything yet? If not, I recommend having a look at the [upgrade guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade), and comparing the v8/v9 code samples in the relevant documentation. If you still get stuck after that, edit your question (there's a link right under it) to show what you tried and we can probably help better.

Comment: useEffect(() => {


    const q = doc(db, 'movie',id);
    const movieSnapshot = getDoc(q);

      movieSnapshot.then((doc) => {
        if(movieSnapshot.exists()){
          setDetailData(movieSnapshot.doc());
        }
        else{
          console.log(' no movie Movie')
        }
      });

    }, [id]);

Answer (score 0):

You're loading the document correctly, but then are somehow not processing the snapshot that is passed to `then()`.

It gets easier if you name the variables more logically:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const q = doc(db, 'movie', id);
  const moviePromise = getDoc(q);
  moviePromise.then((movieDoc) => {
    if (movieDoc.exists()) {
      setDetailData(movieDoc.data());
    } else {
      console.log(' no movie Movie')
    }
  });
}, [id]);
```